# How to copy all file from a folder to other folder use C in Linux

Tags: c

I want to copy all files from a particular folder to other folder use C on Linux.

It can works; however, destination folder is less file than source folder.

I don't know what I'm wrong.Can anyone fix it help me?

This is my code:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc!=3)
   {
      printf("USAGE: programname source destination\n");
      return 1;
   }

   DIR *srcPtr;

   if (mkdir(argv[2],0777)<0)
   {
      printf("Unable to create directory %s (probably it already exists)\n",argv[2]);
   }
   srcPtr=opendir(argv[1]);
   if (srcPtr==NULL)
   {
      printf("BAD OPENDIR %s\n",argv[1]);
      return 1;
   }

   struct dirent *dirPtr;
   struct stat statbuff;
   int fdSrc,fdDest;
   char *path_copia;
   unsigned int len_path_copia;
   unsigned char c;

   chdir(argv[1]);
   while ( (dirPtr=readdir(srcPtr)) !=NULL)
   {
      if (lstat(dirPtr->d_name,&statbuff)<0)
      {
         printf("BAD LSTAT\n");
         return 1;
      }
      if (S_ISREG(statbuff.st_mode))
          //IT's A REGULAR FILE WITH EXECUTION rights for the owner
      {
         //COPY----
         len_path_copia=strlen(argv[2]);
         len_path_copia+=1+strlen(dirPtr->d_name);
         path_copia=(char *)malloc(len_path_copia*sizeof(char));

         strcpy(path_copia,argv[2]);
         strcat(path_copia,dirPtr->d_name);
         printf("Copying %s in %s\n",dirPtr->d_name,path_copia);
         if ( (fdDest=open(path_copia,O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY,(statbuff.st_mode &S_IRWXU)|(statbuff.st_mode &S_IRWXG)|(statbuff.st_mode &S_IRWXO) ) ) <0 )
         {
            printf("BAD OPEN %s\n",path_copia);
            return 1;
         }
         if ( (fdSrc=open(dirPtr->d_name,O_RDONLY))<0 )
         {
            printf("BAD OPEN %s\n",dirPtr->d_name);
            return 1;
         }
         while (read(fdSrc,&c,1)==1)
         {
            write(fdDest,&c,1);
         }
         close(fdSrc);
         close(fdDest);
         free(path_copia);
      }

   }
   chdir("..");
   closedir (srcPtr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is the most awkward way to copy files I've seen so far. Copying bytewise, are you serious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd like to point out that the program is indeed questionable. I think that there are many more well tested alternatives (rsync?), so I can only assume that you wrote this program to learn c. And in that case, much to learn, but this is a great first achievement :)...

Anyway, I compiled your code and found some issues:

- If I for example run copycmd /tmp/tst1/ /tmp/tst2/, at first /tmp/tst2 gets created, then the executable chdirs to /tmp/tst1 and then tries to open tst2/file1 wich is basically /tmp/tst1/tst2/file1. Since the folder /tmp/tst1/tst2 doesn't exist it fails. I fixed that with using a sourceFilename variabele that holds the sourcefilename (same as path_copia, but then for argv[1]) and used that instead of dirPtr->d_name. And I commented out the chdir command.
- if you don't end the first parameter with a /, the exe doesn't work properly (tries to open /tmp/tst1. instead of /tmp/tst1). You should try to fix this yourselve.
- same goes for  the second parameter, but breaks in different way (/tmp/tst2filename instead of /tmp/tst2/filename)

For your issue resulting in less files, I think the issue is because you think it should write to ./argv[2], where it actually writes to ./argv[1]/argv[2]/.

End result after my fixes:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc!=3)
   {
      printf("USAGE: programname source destination\n");
      return 1;
   }

   DIR *srcPtr;

   if (mkdir(argv[2],0777)<0)
   {
      printf("Unable to create directory %s (probably it already exists)\n",argv[2]);
   }
   srcPtr=opendir(argv[1]);
   if (srcPtr==NULL)
   {
      printf("BAD OPENDIR %s\n",argv[1]);
      return 1;
   }

   struct dirent *dirPtr;
   struct stat statbuff;
   int fdSrc,fdDest;
   char *path_copia;
   char *sourceFileName;
   unsigned int len_path_copia;
   unsigned int len_sourceFileName;
   unsigned char c;

//   chdir(argv[1]);
   while ( (dirPtr=readdir(srcPtr)) !=NULL)
   {
      len_sourceFileName = strlen(argv[1]);
      len_sourceFileName += 1+strlen(dirPtr->d_name);
      sourceFileName = malloc(len_sourceFileName*sizeof(char));
      strcpy(sourceFileName,argv[1]);
      strcat(sourceFileName,dirPtr->d_name);

      if (lstat(sourceFileName,&statbuff)<0)
      {
         printf("BAD LSTAT (%s)\n", sourceFileName);
         return 1;
      }
      if (S_ISREG(statbuff.st_mode))
          //IT's A REGULAR FILE WITH EXECUTION rights for the owner
      {
         //COPY----
         len_path_copia=strlen(argv[2]);
         len_path_copia+=1+strlen(dirPtr->d_name);
         path_copia=(char *)malloc(len_path_copia*sizeof(char));

         strcpy(path_copia,argv[2]);
         strcat(path_copia,dirPtr->d_name);
         printf("Copying %s in %s\n",sourceFileName,path_copia);
         if ( (fdDest=open(path_copia,O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY,(statbuff.st_mode &S_IRWXU)|(statbuff.st_mode &S_IRWXG)|(statbuff.st_mode &S_IRWXO) ) ) <0 )
         {
            printf("BAD OPEN %s\n",path_copia);
            return 1;
         }
         if ( (fdSrc=open(sourceFileName,O_RDONLY))<0 )
         {
            printf("BAD OPEN %s\n", sourceFileName);
            return 1;
         }
         while (read(fdSrc,&c,1)==1)
         {
            write(fdDest,&c,1);
         }
         close(fdSrc);
         close(fdDest);
         free(path_copia);
      }

   }
//   chdir("..");
   closedir (srcPtr);
   return 0;
}
```